# Myo android first connection

Tags: android, configuration, sdk, myo

I am very new to android. I am trying to follow this [Myo android tutorial](https://developer.thalmic.com/docs/api_reference/android/getting-started.html#adding-sdk-android-studio)

But I am facing a lot of problems since I don't know a lot about android.
My first problem is with placing the sdk , I downloaded it, and it is written that I have to add the SDK as a dependency in my `build.gradle` file.
When I explored my project, I found 2 `build.gradle` files as in the image:

[image]
So should I add it in which one ?

And how should I add it as an absolute path so I can use the SDK on all devices without changing the path ?

And then they asked me to add these permissions, but where should I add them?

```
// Required for communicating with the Myo device
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

// Required for sending usage data to Thalmic Labs
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1:So should I add it in which one ?
A:You should add it in the "Module:app" one.

Q2:how should I add it as an absolute path so I can use the SDK on all devices without changing the path ?
A:The path of the SDK doesn't relate to the result,the SDK will be wrapped up in the apk,so don't worry about it.

Q3:Where should I add them (permissions)
A:Add them in AndroidManifest.xml.